# Where are these errors coming from

Tags: apt, 12.10

i would love any help with this just to help out i already ran these comands

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

[image]

Comment: SORRY HOPE THIS IS BETTER------>          http://i45.tinypic.com/2v1oy90.png

Comment: Next time, for terminals, it is easier if you select the text in the terminal and right click it to copy it. Then, you can paste it into the body of your post, or a paste at http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa

Comment: The problem is that those PPA's don't have yet packages build for your Ubuntu version(12.10). You should just remove them and find alternative PPA's or just wait to them being updated by their owners.

Answer (score 0):

i would remove these sources from software list go to `update center`-settings or system parammeters `software sources`.Then to `other software` and search for berle/blinking,dockbar,jsevi84,merlwiz79 package just uncheck it.. i guess its not supported yet by this release or try another repository.Then type sudo apt-get update -f && sudo apt-get upgrade and see if its gone. This 404 errors you get when repository is not working

Answer (score 0):

**For Cinnamon**

Remove old PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
```

Add PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

*Will update my answer soon for the rest 404 ppa